# Is it true that children under 6 can legally ride a bicycle on the sidewalk in Denmark?

Tags: legal, denmark

This is quite a specific question but it is important for our vacation.

> Is it true that children under 6 can legally ride a bicycle on the
>   sidewalk in Denmark?

---

I can't find a proper working link but [this document from statensnet.dk](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:AMqrqeuJ0s0J:www.statensnet.dk/pligtarkiv/fremvis.pl%3Fvaerkid%3D12587%26reprid%3D0%26filid%3D2268%26iarkiv%3D1%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&client=ubuntu) says "In some countries, children must cycle on the pavement; in Denmark this is only allowed for children until the age of six[...]"

---

Having now been to Denmark the answer is a) there are lots of cycle lanes  and b) where there weren't no one complained about a 6 year old riding on the sidewalk.

Comment: I don't know when the document you are linking to was published, but it states in the text that much of the content is from a 20 years old study. The information you are quoting may very well be outdated.

Comment: In my country (Netherlands) Children under 6 cycle on the sidewalk in play but not when they go places. When cycling from one point to an other with an adult (or older sibling) also cycling, they go on the road. Not sure how that will be in Denmark though.

Answer (score 7):

No, unless there is a dedicated bicycle path on the sidewalk, it is not allowed for anyone to ride a bicycle there (Færdselsloven § 49 Stk. 5. and § 14 Stk. 4.).

Children below the age of six must be accompanied by a person above 15 years of age to ride a bicycle at all (Færdselsloven § 50).

Answer (score 3):

The under six rule is that they must be accompanied by [someone at least 15 years of age](https://ec.europa.eu/transport/road_safety/specialist/knowledge/pedestrians/special_regulations_for_pedestrians_and_cyclists/traffic_rules_and_regulations_for_cyclists_and_their_vehicles_en).

No cyclist is permitted to ride on the sidewalk if a cycle path is available.

If no cycle path - all cyclists should walk their bikes as it is safe and polite, including under sixers.

Comment: How about if there is no cycle path, which is quite common? For example, https://goo.gl/maps/5hmyinnBm2z .

Comment: @eleanora It is irrelevant if there is a bicycle path somewhere else. Unless the sidewalk itself is separated in a dedicated bicycle path and a field for pedestrians, it is not allowed for anyone to ride a bicycle on the sidewalk.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Thank you. This is quite surprising  if even really small children have to cycle on the road.

Comment: @eleanora Noone forces the children to cycle on the road. They can walk on the sidewalk instead.

Comment: @eleanora - updated my post

Comment: @gef05 You don't mean that adults can't cycle on the road I assume?  Do you mean it is polite if you are with a small child?

Comment: Is it enforced that children may not play with their cycles on the sidewalk/pavement?

Comment: _"If no cycle path - all cyclists should walk their bikes"_ What nonsense is that? There are plenty of ordinary roads without cycle paths, and cycling is certainly allowed on those (though of course not on the sidewalks).

Comment: @HenningMakholm "What nonsense is that?" LOL We're talking about the sidewalk, Henning, not the road. :P